# How to know user reload page by javascript

Tags: javascript

I stored a variable in sessionStorage. When I reload the webpage, sessionStorage don't set this variable to null. I must close the window and open a new one to do this. So, How can I know user reload page by javascript, I need sessionStorage set to null when I reload page

Comment: One thing I can think of is to use `localStorage`. Set some value to it initially.. if the user reloads the page you can check this value and open a new tab.

Comment: you want to know how if the users reloads by javascript, but that is a very odd use case, typically users do not use javascript to reload the page, but use the reload button or something similar

Comment: Have you tried `onbeforeunload`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @sideroxylon

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(e){
    sessionStorage.setItem("var",null);
});
```

This will fire whether the user reloads the page or navigates away.

Comment: Tks u very much :D